# Add default value for time(7) field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I add a default value for `time(7)` field in SQL Server ?

I tried to set "00:00:00" to "default value or binding" in SQL Server Management Studio but it didn't work.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use this T-SQL statement in SSMS:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_TimeDefault DEFAULT '00:00:00' FOR YourTimeColumn
```

If you want to use the visual table designer, use this notation:

[image]

Put your time into single quotes, and put brackets around the value.

Comment: Note: In the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio brackets won't work.  Use parenthesis instead.  i.e.: ('08:00:00')

Comment: Thanks, it worked for the DateTimeOffset field as well